# Installing crypto with python issue

Tags: python, cryptography

I have some python code that uses crypto

```
from Crypto.Random.random import getrandbits
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Random import random
from Crypto.PublicKey import ElGamal
import socket
import time
```

when I run the file i get the error `Traceback (most recent call last): File "./alice_solution.py", line 6, in <module> from Crypto.Random.random import getrandbits ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'`

When i try to install the module *pip install Crypto* I get this error:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting Crypto
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/crypto/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/crypto/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/crypto/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/crypto/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/crypto/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/crypto/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/crypto/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is notavailable.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Crypto (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Crypto
You are using pip version 18.0, however version 20.3b1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Please help... I tried reseaching the issue and found nothing that works

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion on the last line of your error message? Also, which version of python are you running?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk it gives me the same error : `Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping`

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk python3 is 3.7.0 and python is 2.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ssl` module is a standard library module of Python itself. `pip` requires it to be able to fetch resources over TLS. If you compiled this Python yourself you'll need to make sure you have the right dependencies (e.g. openssl development headers, etc). If you did not, check with your platform's package manager to see if there are additional packages to install that provide this.